# Как вычислить максимальную нагрузку сервиса, постепенно ее увеличивая, в jmeter?

Tags: highload, jmeter

Допустим мне нужно вычислить максимальную нагрузку, которую может выдержать сервис, постепенно её наращивая.
Какие настройки лучше всего позволят увидеть сколько пользователей в секунду сервис способен выдержать, перед тем как jmeter получит первую ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

1. `сколько пользователей в секунду` - [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/)
2. `перед тем как jmeter получит первую ошибку` - [Response Codes per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseCodesPerSecond/)
3. Соединить два графика в одном - [Composite Timeline Graph](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/CompositeGraph/)

Все это можно установить с помощью [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Спасибо! Мне помог ваш совет!